# django-recaptcha getting a 500 internal server error from request for widget

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, recaptcha

I've integrated `django-recaptcha` into my project and added the field to one of my form types. I've then put the widget on the page simply by passing the widget's HTML string to my template like so:

```
dctResponse['recaptcha_html'] = form.fields['captcha_field'].widget.render('captcha', 'enter captcha')
```

This adds the following to my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var DjangoRecaptchaOptions = {
          "lang": "en"
        };
            if (typeof RecaptchaOptions !== 'object') {
                RecaptchaOptions = DjangoRecaptchaOptions;
            } else {
                for (key in DjangoRecaptchaOptions) {
                    RecaptchaOptions[key] = DjangoRecaptchaOptions[key];
                }
            }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY&hl=en"></script>
    <noscript>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY&hl=en" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
      <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
      <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' />
    </noscript>
```

When I check the HTML source of the rendered page, that code is visible, but nothing shows up in the browser. When looking at the Javascript console output, I get the following error message:

```
GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY&hl=en 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The strange thing is, when I enter the above address into the browser I get the following response:

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    site : 'PUBLIC_KEY',
    rtl : false,
    challenge : 'CHALLENGE_STRING',
    is_incorrect : false,
    programming_error : '',
    error_message : '',
    server : 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    lang : 'en',
    timeout : 1800
};

document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

What could be happening that's stopping the request from working when called from JS on my page? Could it be a conflict with another script? Also by the way this is running through SSL: the page I'm using it on is served through SSL and the `RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL` variable is set to `True`.

Comment: Did you get the answer to this